# How is Xserver able to tell which device is a mouse or a keyboard?

Tags: xorg, devices, x-server

In these days we don't have to create a custom configuration that sets our devices up, at least when it comes to Xserver. But sometimes you want to change some default parameters. When you do it, you have to create a file under `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/` , for instance `10-mouse.conf`, and put the following in there:

```
Section "InputClass"
    Identifier      "Mouse0"
    Driver          "evdev"
    MatchIsPointer  "yes"
    MatchDevicePath ""
    MatchProduct    ""
    MatchVendor     ""
EndSection
```

It's just a simple example. There's a couple of options that start with `Match*`. Let's pretend we don't know that the device is a mouse. How to determine the appropriate `Match*` parameters? Any idea where to look for them?